# Как отрегулировать высоту background-image?

Tags: html, css, css3, background, background-image

Подскажите, как убрать пустоту снизу?

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url("../img/site-bg.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

[image: Скриншот страницы сайта:]

Comment: Так  надо регулировать высоту блока, которому задан фон.

Comment: Ок, а почему это может не работать? Я пробовал max-height для body, но это ничего не даёт..

Comment: а у Вас фон для body задан? у body не может быть max-height (равно как и просто height), потому что body - это родитель всего и вся :) сделайте блок-обёртку и ему задавайте фон

Comment: Да, но так я получал это: https://www.loom.com/share/af85615bc4e34dec936599680849329b 
Как это победить? Благодарю.

Comment: тогда не очень понятно, что значит "убрать пустоту снизу"? если контента мало, естественно, там будет пустота. либо добавляйте что-то, либо растягивайте имеющийся на всю высоту

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть всё что в **body** в

```
<div class="container">
    ...сюда...
</div>
```

И в CSS переименовать **body** на **.container**

*Пояснение: у body не может быть max-height, поэтому мы внутри него создаём div и по его классу пишем нужные стили*

P.S.: Чтобы удобнее контролировать размеры контейнера, можно добавить ему в CSS что то вроде

```
border: 3px solid green;
```

Тогда он будет обрамлён и лучше заметен.

Удачи в обучении!